# Size of minimal generating set of ideal over Laurent polynomial ring

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-k-theory, computer-algebra

Recently in attacking a problem in algebraic topology relating to the construction of stably-free non-free modules over integral group rings I’ve noticed that it is often fairly easy to reduce to understanding the minimal size of a generating set of an ideal over the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x,x^{-1}]$.

Although I’m somewhat aware that this task isn’t as easy as one might assume, I’ve encountered examples in the literature of generalisations of Grobner bases to this ring, so have been wondering whether this approach might at all be viable. However in what I have skimmed over I have not encountered generalisation of a reduced Grobner basis to this ring, which I assume is what I require.

Would anyone anyone be able to confirm whether or not this approach is viable, in particular direction to any relevant literature or computer algorithm related to this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: A minimal Groebner basis is usually not a generating sets of minimal size.

Comment: The algorithm of Faugère, "A new efficient algorithm for computing Gröbner bases" for polynomial rings over $\mathbb{Z}$ has been implemented in Magma. See https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1261. So pull back your module to $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ first. But as Andrei says, it won't necessarily have minimal size.

Comment: @Dave@Andrei Thanks, I’m glad I won’t be carrying around my incorrect interpretation of “minimal” in this context for more than a few days. I’m assuming there is no general method to achieve such a minimal generating set in this case then?

Comment: Put $y=x-1$ and $I=(y^5,2\times y^4,2\times 3\times y^3,2\times 3\times 5\times y^2,2\times3\times 5\times 7\times y,2\times3\times 5\times 7\times 11)$.  I think that this cannot be generated by fewer than six generators, and that by extending this pattern you can get ideals that need an arbitrarily large number of generators.